# passing a value from ShowDialogForm windows C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form Form1 with a button(Button1) and TextBox(TextBox1).I have another form Form2 which is to be shown after click of Button1 of Form1.I have used following code.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 x = new Form2();//Instance of Form2
            if (x != null)
                x.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Now on Form2 i have a button Button2 and on click Event

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int m = 8; //To pass this value into TextBox1 of Form1
        this.Close();

    }
```

I want to pass this value to Form1 TextBox. Is it possible to pass this value in the same instance of From1.
   What would be suggestion other than creating an instance of Form1 and passing this value to TextBox ? 
Any suggestion is deeply appreciated.

Comment: This is done, or at least, I've done it before with creating a custom event using delegate. I can't provide you with concrete example, but maybe if you google search about how to use custom events to pass data between forms, something will pop up.

Comment: The `if (x != null)` line is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: You don't stand much of chance to get anywhere when you write code like this.  Pick up an introductory book on Winforms programming, you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form2 make the button the form`s accept button and set its DialogResult to OK then create a property and finally:

```
public int YourPropertyToPass {get;private set;}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    YourPropertyToPass = 8; //To pass this value into TextBox1 of Form1
}
```

Then in your form1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 x = new Form2();//Instance of Form2
    if (x != null)
        x.ShowDialog();

    if(x.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       TextBox1.Text = x.YourPropertyToPass.ToString();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a property on the second form that it will use to expose a particular value publicly:

```
public int RenameMe {get; private set;}
```

Set the property when you generate it in the second form's click handler:

```
RenameMe = 8;
```

Then have the parent form read the value:

```
Form2 x = new Form2();
x.ShowDialog();
textbox1.Text = x.RenameMe.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the form1 instance in constructor of form2 and access the Form1 textbox control there.               If you dont want to expose your control outside create a public property of type string in Form2 and set the value in Form2.
Before you close the Form2 you can fill your textbox with the property value.